# Ant build to include jars from sub-directories of lib

Tags: java, ant, java-8, war

I have a very peculiar scenario where I have many sub folders under my project lib directory, which contain dependent jar of the jars I am using. eg.

```
lib/abc.jar
lib/abcDependent/abc1.jar
lib/abcDependent/abc2.jar
lib/abcDependent/abc3.jar
```

Now, since I am doing ant build, I just want to include all the jars to the war without the directory structure. But the below snippet is including the directory structure also.

```
<lib dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="dp-common-${project.major.verson}.${project.minor.version}.jar" />
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </lib>
```

expecting finally to have all jars in lib directory of my war. like

```
lib/abc.jar
lib/abc1.jar
lib/abc2.jar
lib/abc3.jar
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of <lib>, which is just a shorthand for placing a fileset under WEB-INF/lib in the created .war file, use a [mappedresources](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) child element:

```xml
<zipfileset prefix="WEB-INF/lib">
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="dp-common-${project.major.verson}.${project.minor.version}.jar" />
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <flattenmapper/>
    </mappedresources>
</zipfileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have to do it, I would prefer the below approach.

- create a temporary directory with the same desired directory structure to create the `war` file.
- now copy the jar files to destination directory say `lib` in your case.
- and finally create the archive
- remove the temporary directory created once the above is done

This way, you should be able to create either the same or different directory structure for the final package using the intermediate directory.